# Javascript split array equally

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I have the following json:

http://pastebin.com/uxpWk2CY

And I need to split it into a number of arrays depending on the width of the browser.

Here is my javascript:

```
    var imageArray = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

    var splitArrayInto = jQuery(document).width() / 300;
    splitArrayInto = Math.floor(splitArrayInto);

    var seperateImageArrays = array_fill(0, splitArrayInto);

    for(var i = 0; i < splitArrayInto; i++){
        seperateImageArrays[i % splitArrayInto][i] = imageArray[i];
    }
```

When I run that, I get

can't convert undefined to object

seperateImageArrays[i % splitArrayInto][i] = imageArray[i];

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:
Forgot to add the array_fill function.

```
//PHP array_fill
function array_fill (start_index, num, mixed_val) {
    var key, tmp_arr = {};

    if (!isNaN(start_index) && !isNaN(num)) {
        for (key = 0; key < num; key++) {
            tmp_arr[(key + start_index)] = mixed_val;
        }
    }

    return tmp_arr;
}
```

Comment: Did you know that you only have to write `jQuery` in its long form once? By wrapping your code in `(function($) { .... })(jQuery);`, you can use `$` no matter if `noConflict` has been used or not.

Comment: I was told to write jQuery instead of $ for some reason, which I cannot remember.

Comment: It makes sense *once* so it works even with noConflict used. But inside the function I suggested you using `$` is perfectly fine and safe.

Comment: did you check that splitArrayInto  is not 0 sometimes?

Comment: Yes, I checked that. It has the correct value for my screen res. Which is 6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `array_fill` you're not passing the third parameter, so all your array elements are set to `undefined` ... and `undefined` can't be dereferenced with `[i]`.

Consider passing `[]` as the third parameter instead.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `array_fill` from PHPJS, have you considered using [`array_chunk`](http://phpjs.org/functions/array_chunk:306)? This will separate your big array into equally-sized smaller ones (except the last one, which may have less if the number doesn't divide evenly).